# How to set fixed size to PriorityQueue in Java?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a simple question. I am implementing `PriorityQueue` in my project. My question is can i set a fixed size for `PriorityQueue` is Java ?

Comment: No. This is part of `Collection` which grow dynamically based on items we put/add. Better use something like arrays if you are looking for fixed size or write custom implementation.

Comment: How would you expect the semantics of that to work?

Comment: (If you're just trying to get the top k elements of a particular collection, and you can use third-party libraries, consider using Guava's `Optional.leastOf`/`greatestOf`, which have significantly better performance than using a `PriorityQueue`.)

Comment: @MaxZoom No.  Please don't do that.  `MinMaxPriorityQueue` is intended to be used only when you actually need to access both the minimum and the maximum element, and will perform poorly for the case you're describing.  _Do not_ use `MinMaxPriorityQueue` for that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the oracle documentation here states,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html:

> A priority queue is unbounded, but has an internal capacity governing the size of an array used to store the elements on the queue. It is always at least as large as the queue size. As elements are added to a priority queue, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified.

A possible workaround may be that you can check the size before performing any operation:

```
if (q.size() <= QUEUE_LIMIT)
     //your code
```